Upgrade 5.66.0 -> 5.66.2 fails with permission error
I'm upgrading my CiviCRM in stages, because I encountered an error similar to this one.  First I started with 5.66.0 to 5.66.2.
When I get to the DB upgrade stage, I'm hitting a snag.  In the UI, when I hit /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1 -> Upgrade Now -> OK, I just see an empty progress bar and the message [Executed: undefined].
If I switch to the command-line cv (version v0.3.48), and turn on maximum debugging output, I see this:
singersin@s483:~/www/wp$ cv upgrade:db -vvv

Box Requirements Checker
========================

> Using PHP 8.1.28
> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
  /home/singersin/www/wp/php.ini

> Checking Box requirements:
  ✔ The application requires a version matching ">=7.3.0".
  ✔ The application requires the extension "json".
  ✔ The package "psy/psysh" requires the extension "json".
  ✔ The package "nikic/php-parser" requires the extension "tokenizer".
  ✔ The package "psy/psysh" requires the extension "tokenizer".
  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [OK] Your system is ready to run the application.                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

[BootTrait:debug] Start
[BootTrait:debug] Attempting to set verbose error reporting
[BootTrait:debug] Call standard cv bootstrap
[Bootstrap:debug] Options: {
    "dynamicSettingsFile": "phar:///home/singersin/private/bin/cv/lib/settings_location.php",
    "env": "CIVICRM_SETTINGS",
    "prefetch": true,
    "settingsFile": null,
    "search": true,
    "cmsType": null,
    "httpHost": "",
    "output": {}
}
[Bootstrap:debug] Find settings file
[Bootstrap:debug] Load supplemental configuration for "/home/singersin/www/wp/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php"
[Bootstrap:notice] Find CMS root for "/home/singersin/www/wp"
[Bootstrap:notice] Found "wp" in "/home/singersin/www/wp"
[Bootstrap:notice] Simulate web environment in CLI
[Bootstrap:debug] Load settings file "/home/singersin/www/wp/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php"
[Bootstrap:notice] Initialize class loader
[Bootstrap:notice] Call core bootstrap
[Bootstrap:debug] Finished
[BootTrait:debug] Call core bootstrap
[BootTrait:debug] Call CMS bootstrap
[BootTrait:debug] Set active MySQL timezone
[BootTrait:debug] Finished
[PHP Warning] mkdir(): Permission denied at phar:///home/singersin/private/bin/cv/src/Command/UpgradeDbCommand.php:137

In UpgradeDbCommand.php line 138:
                                                                         
  [RuntimeException]                                                     
  Failed to initialize upgrade data folder: /home/singersin/.cv/upgrade  
                                                                         

Exception trace:
  at phar:///home/singersin/private/bin/cv/src/Command/UpgradeDbCommand.php:138
 Civi\Cv\Command\UpgradeDbCommand->getUpgradeFile() at phar:///home/singersin/private/bin/cv/src/Command/UpgradeDbCommand.php:47
 Civi\Cv\Command\UpgradeDbCommand->execute() at phar:///home/singersin/private/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:127
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///home/singersin/private/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:637
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///home/singersin/private/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:190
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///home/singersin/private/bin/cv/src/Application.php:67
 Civi\Cv\Application->doRun() at phar:///home/singersin/private/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:101
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///home/singersin/private/bin/cv/src/Application.php:33
 Civi\Cv\Application::main() at phar:///home/singersin/private/bin/cv/bin/cv:28
 require() at /home/singersin/private/bin/cv:14

I'm assuming this is because I don't have permission to create directories in $HOME (the site's hosting provider doesn't allow it):
$ ls -ld ~
drwxr-x---+ 15 root singersin 4096 Mar  9  2020 /home/singersin

Can I run the DB upgrades manually, or specify a different temporary directory for it to perform its work somehow?  Trying HOME=$HOME/private/tmp cv upgrade:db didn't work, it still tried to create .cv/upgrade in the original non-writeable location.
I'm using CiviCRM with Wordpress 6.5.3 and MySQL 5.7.44.  Thanks.
########################################
UPDATE - apparently HOME is special and can't be overridden:
$ HOME=foo BAR=baz php -r '$home=getenv("HOME"); $bar=getenv("BAR"); echo("[$home;$bar]\n");'
[/home/singersin;baz]

The *.cli PHP binaries seem to have this behavior; *.cgi binaries will let me override HOME, but cv refuses to run from a CGI binary:
$ HOME=$HOME/private/tmp php81.cgi bin/cv
Content-type: text/html


The application may only be invoked from a command line, got "cgi-fcgi"

I'm still wondering if there's some place I can find the DB update steps and just run them manually.

Looking at cv's code, using HOME should work, just the target folder needs to exist first. Is that the problem?

@Demerit I'm not sure why HOME isn't working either, but when I run HOME=$HOME/private/tmp cv upgrade:db I still get the error Failed to initialize upgrade data folder: /home/singersin/.cv/upgrade as if it's not seeing the set value.  Does cv do anything special to not inherit environment variables from the caller?

I'm also not sure why the line number is reported as line 138 when the exception should be thrown around line 195.  I checked that I have the latest cv, maybe it's just wrong about its line numbering in the .phar file?

For the line numbers, the phar is compressed/repackaged. If you extract it to a folder you'll see it's the same code. php -r '$p = new Phar("cv.phar"); $p->extractTo("/path/to/some/folder");'

If it wasn't recognizing env vars, then the line above it would trigger an error: if (empty($home). Extreme thought: If you do php -i | grep Thread is "thread safety" disabled? Although then I would expect $home to be false still.

I see Thread Safety => disabled in the output of php -i.

@Demerit apparently PHP specifically doesn't allow HOME to be overridden, I added some updates at the bottom of the question.

I'm facing the same permission issue on my $HOME because the hosting provider doesn't allow creating directories there. It would be nice if we could pass a parameter like "--tmp" to the cv upgrade:db command specifying a writable folder location. Otherwise it seems I can only do the Civi db upgrade manually via the web UI.
